# How to select a specific row in views-view.tpl.php?

Tags: 7, views, theming

I'm customizing a specific views block and trying to separate the 2 first rows in a "top" div(wrape it)

[image]

Comment: Please post code as code block, not image. Also, what exactly do you want to do? Select in what sense? Mark as "selected" for user? Read it's data? What do you need to do with that row?

Comment: Why vote in negative? The question is clear: "I'm trying to separate the 2 first rows in a top div(wrape it)".

Comment: You guys should not vote like that in questions what you dont know what about it is. Again, the question is clear, I have been supported in other sites and it isn't my first time in StackExchange sites.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal SE, sorry you arent feeling supported.  Here are some pieces of information that would make your question easier to read.  1. what is the template filename that you have a screenshot of there  2. why is the displayed code not working for you 3. do you have devel module enabled, or are you able to use it 4. can you add a picture of the views settings in the advanced area mentioned by Daedalus in his answer?

Comment: Hi @DeveloperWeeks the template is views-view.tpl.php like I said. Nevermind, I just found the answer to this question thank to hints of Daedalus and people of Drupal.org and facebook drupal groups.

Comment: @DocKodam "Unclear what you're asking" is **especially** for questions that make it hard for people to know what they are about...

Comment: @Mołot again, if one person understand the "template nesting level" of views/drupal, so he can clearly understand this question like other people already answered me in other places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of question has come up for me and I found that going a few layers back (or up) and head  towards `rows style output` solved my issue. If you edit that view you want to override, then go to the `Advanced` column, expand it, then click on Theme: `information.` In that overlay window you can see they will suggest what to call a .tpl.php to override the different levels. I would choose the one that has `row style output.` From there, with a debugger, I am sure you can figure out how to isolate the first two rows. Hope this helps you find the solution you need.